# single WebView layout to view urls from my main activity

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to reuse a custom xml which I for various links from my main Activity.

I assume it's using a LayoutInflater.
But I am  struggling with the code.

I was using the main_Activity xml for the code originally.
But I thought it would save space in the app if it inflated the same WebView for all the links within the app.

this is the xml for the custom layout

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/MyWebView">

  <WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webViewCustom">

 </WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

then this is the Java code I have tried.
I think that might be where my problem lies

```
switch (position){
 case 0:
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(view.getWidth(),view.getHeight());
 lp.leftMargin = (int) view.getX();
  lp.topMargin = (int) view.getY();

  LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.custom_webview, null);
                                webViewCustom.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                                webViewCustom.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                                webViewCustom.loadUrl(AeonnoxCusBckGrndMJDUrl);

                                MjdLayout.addView(ll, lp);

                                break;
```

this is how originaly had it within my mainActivity java. and each link has a seperate webView attached to a drawer. but i want 1 Activity that inflates/Opens all links when each button is pressed it just reuses the one view

```
TrustedSellersDrawer.openDrawer(MJDwebViewDrawerRight);

MJDwebViewDrawerRight.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

MJDwebViewDrawerRight.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

MJDwebViewDrawerRight.loadUrl(AeonnoxCusBckGrndMJDUrl);
```

The logcat

```
11-13 18:13:46.578      552-587/? W/System.err﹕ at       libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
11-13 18:13:46.578      552-587/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
11-13 18:13:46.578      552-587/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
11-13 18:13:46.578      552-587/? W/System.err﹕ at com.sec.android.hardware.SecHardwareInterface.setBatteryADC(SecHardwareInterface.java:393)
11-13 18:13:46.578      552-587/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.server.power.PowerManagerService$DisplayBlankerImpl$1.run(PowerManagerService.java:5324)
11-13 18:13:46.578      552-587/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 11-13 18:13:46.578      552-587/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-13 18:13:46.578      552-587/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
11-13 18:13:46.578      552-587/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
11-13 18:13:46.578      552-587/? W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
11-13 18:13:46.578      552-587/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
11-13 18:13:46.578      552-587/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
11-13 18:13:46.578      552-587/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
11-13 18:13:46.578      552-587/? W/System.err﹕ ... 8 more
```

my last few questions have been marked down quite alot for unknown reasons, so please be nice.

Comment: Whats the question? i cant see it. and please, if needed, post the logcat output before we ask for it.

Comment: the question is how can i make a layout that inflates for my url links, at the moment i have it set up to every web link has its own webView. i thought id would save room by making one Main webView and then each link could just inflate the view.

Comment: Cant see the relation between inflating a view and loading urls in the webview, also your logcat isnt full looks like its a file access exception...

Comment: i have about 50 links web links and each one opens its own Webview attached to a drawer on my main view. i want it in a seperate xml that can be called from my main activity. it dosent have to inflate. i just assumed it would be something like that. is there a method i can use that just calls this xml which i called custom_webView.xml. thanks for taking the time to answer me though